# How to make Python socket accept connections in background in a Flask App?

Tags: python, sockets, flask, websocket

I am a beginner in Flask.
I am working on a small website in Flask, my goal is to set up a socket accepting connections in background. Here is the code :

```
@app.route('/dashboard/')
@login_required
def dashboard_page():
    s = lancer_socket()
    accepter_msg(s)   #if i comment out this line, the template loads
    return render_template('dashboard.html',info = info,tel_conns=tel_conns)
```

However, the function 'accepter_msg' makes the template not load. Here is the code:

```
 def accepter_msg(socket):
    while True:
        Client, addresse = socket.accept()
        print('Connecté à: ' + addresse[0] + ':' + str(addresse[1]))
        start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client, ))
```

**My goal is to load the dashboard page, and to make the socket accept the connections and receive data in background** (after that, i will refresh the template with the modified variables (info and tel_conns)  :

```
render_template('dashboard.html',info = info,tel_conns=tel_conns)
```

I need to use a simple python socket and not a socketio or anything else. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up a socket server to accept websocket connections, consider using [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `socket.accept` call is a *blocking* function call, which means the function does not return until a client connects to it.  So your `render_template` will not even start when this *blocking* function call does not return. The function does not return simply means that it is hanging there.

```
Client, addresse = socket.accept()
```

If you really want to use `socket.accept`, you need it make it a non-blocking socket. How to do that?  This realpython article has nice examples.

https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Also read this official documentation *Socket Programming HOWTO* to get a good understanding of socket programming.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `while True`loop that blocks the following command.